# SNMPv3 Trap Unique Content Separator required

Tags: linux, unix, networking, snmp, net-snmp

I send a SNMPv3 Trap and separate its fields using `|` and `;` but these characters are also appearing in my trap, which confuses my parser at trap receiving end. I also tried most of the characters e.g. `:,".><!@#$%^&*()`
but all these single line character appear in the trap. I also tried special symbols like **`€,¾,½`** but Linux is not accepting these characters.
I need a single character separator.

Could you suggest any Key that can be entered from from Keyboard and works in Linux?

Comment: I read this question several times but I failed to find how it relates to programming. If you disagree, please nemtion what language & library you're using, and post a snippet of the failing code.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment Operator Worked **=**, Since it is nearly impossible of assignment operator occurring in trap content.